# python __init__ class attribute, when will class Test be ready?

Tags: python, init

First program in book fluent Python. I simplified the program.

```
class Test:
    a = 15
    def __init__(self):
        self.att = a

t = Test()
print(t.att)
```

It didn't work, and if i use

```
self.att = Test.a
```

then it worked.
Why should I always use Test.a even in class Test?
I learned java, and I don't have to do so.

Also, here comes another problem.

```
class Test:
    a = 15
    def __init__(self, b=Test.a):
        self.att = b

t = Test()
print(t.att)
```

It didn't work. I searched on the site.
And is the reason that:
default arguments should be defined while function definition, not till being called?

And since

```
self.att = Test.a
```

worked, so function content will be checked for valid till being called?

Am I right?

Class Test will be ready after #1, but before, I used Test.a, because it didn't check function content before being called. right?

```
class Test:
    a = 15
    def __init__(self):
        self.att = Test.a 
    #1
t = Test() 
print(t.att)
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#classes

Answer (score 1):

Members like that need to be accessed like this: `self.a` (even in the `__init__` method)

```
class Test:
    a = 15
    def __init__(self):
        self.att = self.a

t = Test()
print(t.att)
```

Comment: Why do they need to be accessed by `self.a`? (Suggested answer update - not expecting a comment)

Answer (score 1):

> I learned java, and I don't have to do so.

But if you compare Java with Python, you will notice that you will have to prefix `self` for every instance member, and you actually need your methods to take that `self` argument in all the time. So you cannot really expect Java behavior here.

But just like with methods or instance variables, you can access *class members* using `self` as well:

```
class Test:
    a = 15
    def __init__(self):
        self.att = self.a
```

At runtime of `__init__`, `self` will refer to the instance of your `Test` type. So when you want to access anything on the instance, you need to do that on `self`. For class members, all its members are also visible on the instance (unless they are hidden by instance members), so `self.a` works just like `Test.a` works. You can also try this with your created instance `t`: `t.a` will also work even though there is no *instance* member `a`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is `__init__` is executed on object creation; inside your `__init__` function scope there is no `a` variable defined. How should it know you mean the `a` defined in the class?

When stating `Test.a` you explicity tell python to use the class attribute. When you are using `self.a` Python uses the **MRO** lookup process to find the `a` attribute.

```
class Test:
    a = 15
    def __init__(self):
        self.att = self.a 
    #1
t = Test() 
print(t.att)
```